# GeoMarker opacity

Tags: undocumented, geographics

I was surprised today when I discovered that [`GeoMarker`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoMarker.html) seems to ignore the `Opacity` directive in `GeoGraphics`. This can be demonstrated using the first example in the documentation:

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["OutlineMap"], 
  Opacity[.5],
  Polygon[Entity["Country", "Italy"]], 
  GeoMarker[Entity["City", {"Rome", "Lazio", "Italy"}]]}]
```

[image: wrong opacity]

The country's polygon is respecting the `Opacity` directive, but `GeoMarker` ignores it.

How to properly set the opacity of `GeoMarker`s?

Answer (score 4):

Probably the most simple way to set the opacity of `GeoMarker`s is with an undocumented usage of its `"Color"` parameter. It appears to support [`Directive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directive.html)s, so the opacity can be set the following way:

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["OutlineMap"], Opacity[.5], 
  Polygon[Entity["Country", "Italy"]], 
  GeoMarker[Entity["City", {"Rome", "Lazio", "Italy"}], 
   "Color" -> Directive[Opacity[.5], RGBColor[0.790588, 0.201176, 0.]]]}]
```

[image: correct opacity]

Comment: Do you mind tell us how to find it?

Comment: @yode I had a hunch and was lucky it worked. :)

Comment: "Color" is a documented option for [GeoMarker](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoMarker.html)

Comment: @BobHanlon Yes, but it doesn't mention it can take other arguments than color objects.

Comment: [RGBColor] (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RGBColor.html) has an optional fourth argument for opacity.

Comment: Right, you can pot this as an answer, too