# Adjusting opacity in map overlays

Tags: dataset, curated-data, geographics

I am currently working with rainfall data from hurricane Harvey in order to better understand how to allocate resources in the event of another disaster. I want to accomplish a few things given this data set.

```
Import["http://www.srh.noaa.gov/data/ridge2/Precip/qpehourlyshape/\
2017/201708/20170826/nws_precip_2017082607.tar.gz"]
```

[image: Output]

The following are the elements of the data set:

```
  {"Centering", "CentralScaleFactor", "CoordinateSystem", \
  "CoordinateSystemInformation", "Data", "Datum", "Graphics", \
  "GraphicsList", "GridOrigin", "InverseFlattening", "LayerNames", \
  "LayerTypes", "LinearUnits", "Projection", "ProjectionName", \
  "ReferenceModel", "SemimajorAxis", "SemiminorAxis", "SpatialRange", \
  "StandardParallels"}
```

What I want to do is to scale down the opacity of the points on the graph based on the heights of the rainfall (lower opacity for lower rainfall heights) so I can get a clear image of the hurricane. I also want to show rainfall for only Texas and neighboring states. This may seem like a general question but I checked the documentation and I am new to $Mathematica$ and working with large data sets like this one. Thank you to whomever is taking the time to answer or edit this question.

Comment: If you provide the code of how you generate the picture would be fine for helping you.

Comment: Have you take a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118744/geomarker-opacity?rq=1)?

Comment: The picture is generated from the single import command seen above. If you type "Elements" after the link in the import command the data set has its elements listed above.

Comment: So do I have to understand that from the information of the picture, you get all the data of the elements, and you have in other set the rainfall for each point?

Comment: Here is the link from where I got the data set from: https://roadtolarissa.com/hurricane/ This is from data science weekly. The author of the article was working with the same data set in r. Is there a similar way to do this in mathematica?

Comment: You mean about animations on hurricane and rainfalls? Virtually, yes, you only need data from rainfalls, wind speed, etc, and how they change with time...Overlay data with transparency over maps is posible..., as far I know

Comment: The .tar folder has the file nws_precip_2017082607.shp that contains the global value in inches of each point.